# SQLite: Parameter and field name substitution with Python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am relatively new to SQL and sqlite3 in general, and have a question about using question mark or named style in executions.

I have several databases with a table called `structures`, and I have made a method in a class in Python that extracts the n'th value of some column using

```py
def get_nth(self, col_name, n):
    cursor = self.con.cursor()
    if n == -1:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT {col_name} FROM structures ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
    else:
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT {col_name} FROM structures WHERE id == {n}")

    try:
        val = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
    except IndexError as e:
        print("Faulty database - no 'structures' table found")
        raise e
    return val
```

Having googled about other sqlite3-related problems, I found that executing with `f-strings` or `str.format` will be vulnerable to injection attacks, and therefore I tried altering the execution, according to [Cursor Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute), to:

```py
if n == -1:
    cursor.execute("SELECT ? FROM structures ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", (col_name, ))
else:
    cursor.execute("SELECT ? FROM structures WHERE id == ?", (col_name, n))

print(cursor.fetchall()[0][0])
```

This outputs the column name itself instead of the actual value, since .execute uses  `'id'` and not `id` if `col_name='id'`.

#### Question:

Is there a way to use question mark or named style in this way?

Comment: Use a hybrid: `cursor.execute("SELECT {col_name} FROM structures WHERE id == ?", (col_name, n))`.  The bit to protect against injection is the value, not nessecarily the column name.  Protect the value, and the column name is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In agreement with the answer from @SergeBallesta, you can do something like:

```
sql = 'SELECT {col_name} FROM structures WHERE id = ?'.format(col_name=colname)
cursor.execute(sql, [n])
```

Which uses a hybrid of the two conventions.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only pass *data* in parameterized queries, but neither SQL words like `INSERT`, `SELECT`or `UPDATE`, nor names like table or field names.